# Pandas: Get the col name for the min value within each row and get % difference compared to the rest of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
LF  RF  LR  RR  
11  22  33  44  
23  43  23  12  
33  23  12  43
```

What I want to accomplish is a calculation (The purpose is to identify which column within each row has the lowest value and determine a percentage compared to the rest of the cols mean). 
For example:
Identify the min value in r1, which is 11 and col name (LF). The rest of the cols mean is (22+33+44)/3= 33. Then we calculate the percentage difference 11/33 = 0.333

Expected output:

```
LF  RF  LR  RR  Min_Col dif(%)
11  22  33  44  LF      0.333
23  43  23  12  RR      0.404
33  23  12  43  LR      0.364
```

a proper way of writing the equation would be:

```
(min_value)/(sum_rest_of_cols/3)
```

Note: I need to have a column that indicates for each row which column is the lowest (This is a program to identify problems, so within the error message we want to be able to tell the user which column it is, that is giving the problems)

EDITED:

My code (df_inter is the original df which I am locing to only get the desired columns to perform this calculation):

```
df_exc = df_inter.loc[:,['LF_Strut_Pressure', 'RF_Strut_Pressure', 'LR_Strut_Pressure' ,'RR_Strut_Pressure']]
    df_exc['dif(%)'] = df_exc.min(1) * 3 / (df_exc.sum(1) - df_inter.min(1))
    df_exc['Min_Col'] = df_exc.iloc[:, :-1].idxmin(1)
    print(df_exc)
```

My Output:

```
                            LF_Strut            RF_Strut           LR_Strut            RR_Strut    dif(%)      Min_Col
truck_id                                                                                                         
EX7057             0.000000           0.000000           0.000000           0.000000    0.0000     LF_Strut
EX7105             0.000000           0.000000           0.000000           0.000000    0.0000     LF_Strut
EX7106             0.000000           0.000000           0.000000           0.000000    0.0000     LF_Strut
EX7107             0.000000           0.000000           0.000000           0.000000    0.0000     LF_Strut
TD6510         36588.000000       36587.000       36587.00000       36587.00    0.8204     RF_Strut
TD6511         36986.000000       36989.000       36987.00000       36989.00    0.8220     LF_Strut
TD6512         27704.000000       27705.000       27702.00000       27705.00    0.7757     LR_Strut
```

The problem is: When doing the calculation for TD6510  ( 36587 / ( (36587 + 36587 + 36588) / 3 ) ) = 0.9999999 .. not 0.8204 . I tried replicating where 0.8204 came from, I was unsuccesful. Thanx for al l the help and support.

Comment: `df.idxmin(1)
`

Comment: Thank you, it worked to get the column name of the min value for each row. I am still stuck at how to perform the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the text in a file called "textfile.txt". This should be useful:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('textfile.txt', sep = ' ')
df['min']   = df[['LF','RF','LR','RR']].min(axis=1)
df['sum_3'] = df[['LF','RF','LR','RR']].sum(axis=1)- df['min']
df['sum_3_div3'] = df['sum_3']/3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working perfectly after I added ```df['sum_3_div3'] = df['min']/(df['sum_3']/3)``` .. Saved my day. Thanx, cheers

Answer (score 2):

First we use `idxmin`

```
df['dif(%)']=df.min(1)*3/(df.sum(1)-df.min(1))
df['Min_Col']=df.iloc[:,:-1].idxmin(1)
df
   LF  RF  LR  RR    dif(%) Min_Col
0  11  22  33  44  0.333333      LF
1  23  43  23  12  0.404494      RR
2  33  23  12  43  0.363636      LR
```

Comment: Thanx, this seems to be working.. I am not getting the numbers I expect, but I believe the problem is the way my df is arranged. Im fixing it, and ill confirm once again.

Comment: I am not getting the results as expected, I am editing the original question to show my code and my output

Answer (score 1):

Using `idxmin` and `df.mask()` with `df.isin()` and `df.min()`:

```
final = df.assign(Min_Col=df.idxmin(1),
       Diff=df.min(1).div(df.mask(df.isin(df.min(1))).mean(1)))
```

---

```
print(final)

   LF  RF  LR  RR Min_Col      Diff
0  11  22  33  44      LF  0.333333
1  23  43  23  12      RR  0.404494
2  33  23  12  43      LR  0.363636
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do usual calculation, the min col is given by `idxmin`

```
# find the mins in each row
mins = df.min(axis=1)

# compute mean of the other values
other_means = (df.sum(1) - mins).div(df.shape[1]-1)


(mins /other_means)*100
```

Output:

```
0    33.333333
1    40.449438
2    36.363636
dtype: float64
```